# Find out a function symbol's visibility in an object file (.o)

Tags: linux, gcc, visibility, elf, binutils

I only cares about default/hidden visibility.
The .o file is not compiled with IPO.

How to find out a symbol's visibility in the .o file?

Why I have to find it out from .o file:
On certain platform, I ran into a gcov.a which appears problematic.
And I have to figure out where it is wrong.
1. I cannot know how exactly the toolchain is configured and built.
2. As part of libgcc magic, figure it out from source code is extremely difficult.

Comment: Have you tried the `nm` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the visibility of a symbol in an object file by examining
the file's symbol table with `objdump -t`. If the symbol is `hidden` it
will be labelled `.hidden` in the 6th field of its `objdump` record, followed
by its name. If its visibility is `default` there will be no such label and
the 6th field will be the name (the usual case). For example:

**foo.c (default visibility)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo");
}
```

Compile and examine:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC foo.c
$ objdump -t foo.o | grep foo
foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 foo.c
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000013 foo
```

**foo.c (hidden visibility)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) void foo(void)
{
    puts("foo");
}
```

Recompile and re-examine:

```
$ gcc -c -fPIC foo.c
$ objdump -t foo.o | grep foo
foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 foo.c
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000013 .hidden foo
```

Comment: In general, using `objdump` for anything on an ELF system is a mistake: use `readelf` instead. `objdump` is from `COFF` days, and its model of the world is severely outdated, and it will outright lie to you when mapping non-trivial ELF concepts back to its simplified world view.